# Route incoming SMPP messages to specific SMSC in Kannel/OpenSMPPBox

Tags: sms, smpp, kannel, opensmppbox

I have clients connecting to me through SMPP connections (OpenSMPPBox) and then, they are sent with Kannel to SMSCs. I would like to route particular numbers to specific SMSCs, but I am not sure whether it is possible.

If anyone has any experience with this, please let me know,

All best,
Olsi.

Comment: It is quite possible to do what you want with a custom made application. Are you only interested in solutions that work with OpenSMPPBox?

Comment: Whatever works would be fine for me. Do you know of any other solutions?

Comment: Hi Olsi, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

In order to route MT messages through a specific channel, the following steps are required. Suppose we want all MT messages from ESME *internal-esme*, which is connected to opensmppbox, to be sent to smsc-id *external-smsc* in bearerbox.

1. To do this, create the smsc-route group in /etc/kannel/opensmppbox.conf:

```
group = smsc-route
smsbox-id = internal-esme
smsc-id = external-smsc
```

2. Now you need to add an allowing rule to smsc-id *external-smsc*, which will mean: messages that are defined with the smsc_id parameter and which match the specified ones are allowed to be sent. Example in /etc/kannel/kannel.conf:

```
group = smsc
smsc-id = external-smsc
smsc = smpp
...
allowed-smsc-id="external-smsc"
```

3. Now it is necessary to deny in the remaining channels smsc_id *external-smsc*, so add to each remaining channel:

```
group = smsc
smsc-id = provider1
smsc = smpp
...
denied-smsc-id="external-smsc"

group = smsc
smsc-id = provider2
smsc = smpp
...
denied-smsc-id="external-smsc"
```

The allowed-smsc-id and denied-smsc-id parameters allow names to be enumerated with *;*. Thus, we created rules with explicit routing through a specific smsc-id *external-smsc* for ESME internal-esme. Do not forget, to determinate MT routing, Kannel selects the appropriate channel for sending (see gw/smscconn.c, smscconn_usable function).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to manage this and ended up using NowSMS, a paid solution.